# CSS hover transform moves my element out of the hover

Tags: html, css

I'm animating my navigation links, and scaling them up on hover. Like so:

```
nav#nav a:hover
  color coal
  transform scale(1.64)
  transform-origin center -109%
```

This causes the element to move out from under the cursor, reversing the effect, causing it to move back, redoing the hover, stuck in this ugly loop.

How can the hover effect be maintained?

Comment: Please make a fiddle to show the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Without actual code I can only give a conceptual answer:

Could you put the item that is animated inside of a div that doesn't change size and apply the hover to that? So you hover over the div it animates the inner object, but the div doesn't move so even after the inner object changes the mouse is still hovering over the div.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. This would work if I were using JavaScript. I'm using pure CSS. Thanks, yeah, wanted to get the question up quickly. I'll try to get some demo code up.

Comment: Even with pure CSS couldnt you do this? If your wrapper is ".wrap" you could .wrap:hover a { color: coal; transform scale(1.64) transform-origin center -109%} ?